# Error in creating ionic app

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I get this error while creating an ionic blank app. Please help me to solve this.

```
Error with start undefined
Error initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
```

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Try googling for "ionic create app error with the spawned command npminstall". Seems to be a bug with certain npm versions. Did you try to update npm itself?

Comment: yes i tried to update the npm with the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Update your ionic version.

Try updating Node to higher version.

Uninstalled node, npm, nvm, ionic, and cordova.

Then, Reinstall nvm, and use it to reinstall node/npm. Reinstall other components.

Comment: I updated to higher version but still I get the same error.

Comment: tell me the version. Try uninstalling and see .. Thats one of the familiar error mostly we get, and upgrading the node to 5.4 actually works pretty fine.

Comment: The node version is v6.10.0

Comment: @Sarah31: Can you try to  reinstall and see. There is none other thing I could think of presently.